# i got 'Controller' doesn't conform to the bound 'GetxController*' of the type parameter 'T'. problem here

Tags: flutter

```
class Controller extends GetxController {
  var todoList = <Todos>[].obs;

  @override
  void onInit() {
    _configureAmplify();
    super.onInit();
  }


=============================================================



class Controller extends GetxController {
  var todoList = <Todos>[].obs;

  @override
  void onInit() {
    _configureAmplify();
    super.onInit();
  }
```

[as you can see here i got GetxController here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zIGGU.png)

[but as you can see i got 'Controller' doesn't conform to the bound 'GetxController*' of the type parameter 'T'. problem here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LMBRJ.png)

Can someone help me to fix that problem there are few resources on the internet and it didn't help me i can't solve the problem

Answer (score 0):

try to change import above from

```
import 'package:get_state_manager/get_state_manager.dart'
```

to

```
 import 'package:get/get.dart'
```

from HomeScreen